# Как передать неизвестное кол-во input`ов с помощью js?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Есть форма.
В ней есть заранее неизвестное кол-во input'ов `folder_name` . Их кол-во регулируется кнопкой `copyBtn`.
Пользователь заполняет форму, создает нужное ему кол-во input'ов и отправляет форму.
Если отправлять форму традиционно то через POST приходит массив и с им работаем.
А вот через ajax приходит только значение первого input'a.
Подскажите, как переделать js-код для корректной работы?

форма:

```
<form action="#" id="formId">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Название объекта</label>
        <input name="name" type="text" value="" placeholder="Название объекта" id="name" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group copy">
        <input type="text" name="folder_name[]" id="folder_name" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Наим. тома">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" id="copyBtn"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Добавить раздел</button>
    </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="createObject" value="Отправить"/>
</form>
```

JS-код

Создаем дополнительный input

```
$('#copyBtn').click(function(){
    $('.copy').append( $('#folder_name').eq(0).clone() );
    return false;
});
```

Собираем данные с input'ов и отправляем в обработчик

```
$("#createObject").bind("click", function(){ 
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var folder_name = document.getElementById("folder_name").value;

    if(name == "" )
    {
        alert("Укажите название Объекта!");
        return false;
    }
    else if(folder_name == "" )
    {   
        alert("Тома пусты!!");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        $.ajax ({
        type:"POST",
        url: "ajax/objectedit/createobject.php",
        data: {"name":name,
               "folder_name[]":folder_name,
                 },
        beforeSend: funcBeforeObject,
        success: funcSuccessObject
    });
    }

});
```

Пробовал сделать так:

```
var folder_name= [];
$('input.folder_name').each(function() {
    folder_name.push(this.value);
});
```

В итоге получаю вообще пустоту.

Comment: $("form").serialize()

Comment: `id="folder_name"` Должен быть на странице один.

Comment: а каким образом тогда идентифицировать input'ы, если их будет например 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('form').on('submit', (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();
 const result = $('form').serialize();
 alert(result);

 return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formId">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Название объекта</label>
        <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Название объекта" id="name" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group copy">
        <label>Название папки</label>
        <input type="text" name="folder_name" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Наим. тома">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="createObject" value="Отправить"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Очень помогли!

Answer (score 1):

просто добавляем число в конец и потом  когда отправляем маппим инпуты в объект
Добавь имена обычно она используется для отправки форм как ключ для оставления объекта

По умолчанию самый первый штзге будет с id #folder_name_0 и потом при добавлении будут id

folder_name_1
folder_name_2
folder_name_3

```
var index = 0;
$('#copyBtn').click(function(){
  let newInput = $(`#folder_name_0`).eq(0).clone()
  newInput.id = `folder_name_${index++}`
  $('.copy').append(newInput);
  return false;
});

let values = [...document.getElementById('formId').getElementsByTagName('input')].map(v => {
  return {
    name: v.name,
    value: v.value,
  }
});
```

Comment: Что-то счетчик input'ов  у меня не срабатывает....